# How to create a floating label in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I am working some WPF application which required a floating label. I implemented a label textbox everything and it is working fine. But I like to know how to create a floating label instead of a normal label. Attaching the image that I needed down. if someone good at this WPF styling things help me out here.
[floating label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p33O4.png)

Answer (score 1):

For me the best solution is to use the [Material Design in Xaml](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) to do it.

If you are looking for the exact same thing as in the image follow the documentation to change the colors and if you navigate through the Demo App you'll find an exact same field in the "Fields" page from the menu on the "Outlined fields" section.

Plus, the package offers many pretty option that you can find useful.

If you have further question you can ask me in the comment and if you have trouble, the material-design-in-xaml tag exists on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sure Ximaze, let me check this.